# rspec: validate association for serializers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, serialization

```
# model
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
end

# model spec
RSpec.describe Post, type: :model do
  subject { build(:post) }
  it { is_expected.to have_many(:comments) }
end
```

The above is the test case to validate the `has_many` association for model. Similarly, is there any option to validate the same for Serializer?.

```
# serializer
class PostSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  has_many :comments
end

# serializer spec
RSpec.describe PostSerializer, type: :serializer do
  let(:serializer) { PostSerializer.new(create(:post)) }

  # validation for `has_many` association.
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there are RSpec matchers for `active_model_serializers` which is a separate third-party gem. Your best bet is to use the serializer to generate a hash with `as_json` and compare the result it in your tests.